# Since/Until date on javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to do the method about since/until but I worried that there're error when month has changed. I don't want to calculate when the time left or passed.

My Code:

```
var graduatedDay = new Date();
var day = graduatedDay.getDate();
var month = graduatedDay.getMonth() + 1;
//(I plus one because month value is 0-11)
var year = graduatedDay.getFullYear();

if ((day >= 15 && month >= 3) || (month > 4) && year >= 2015) {
    document.write("Since today you have graduated");
} else {
    document.write("You aren't graduated yet");
}
```

I don't sure that above code is given but I have my concept like that

Answer (score 0):

If you are calculating the year passed after month 3 and day 15, then you dont have to check that month > 4. Try like this

```
if(((day>=15 && month>=3) || month > 4) && year >= 2015 )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found that it's not effective when day is more than current date.

I test with 31st of March 2014

I get result "You aren't graduated yet."

Comment: I'll try again from your advice

Comment: Thanks, It works too.

I don't care about vote but I can clear my problem. I'm happy

Answer (score 0):

Why not just compare with another date object?

```
var graduatedDay = new Date();
var x = new Date('2013-03-15');
if (graduatedDay > x)
  {document.write("Since today you have graduated")} 
else
  {document.write("You aren't graduated yet")}
```

I believe the error you might be having in your original code is an incorrect `(`

```
if( day>=15 && month>=3 && year >= 2015 )
```

Comment: Don't pass strings to the Date constructor, it calls *Date.parse*, which is largely inmplementation dependent. Some browsers will parse '2013-03-05' as local and some as UTC (though that doesn't matter here, it just highlights the inconsistency, even for standardised parts of *Date.parse*).

Comment: I see thanks for the heads up. I think your answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to use date objects (assuming the graduation day is 2015-03-14):

```
var graduateDay = new Date(2015, 2, 14)
var today = new Date();

if (today > graduateDay) {
    document.write("Since today you have graduated");

} else {
    document.write("You aren't graduated yet");
}
```

Comment: Can I do this with time too?

If Graduation is finished at 3 PM

Comment: Yes: `new Date(2015, 2, 14, 15)`. You can specify year, month, day, hour, minutue, second, milliseconds. Any missing arguments are treated as zero (except for day, which is 1 if missing). See [ES5 §15.9.3.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1)

Comment: You can use either '01' or 1, the Date constructor calls [*ToNumber*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) on all the arguments so strings are converted to numbers according to that algorithm.

Comment: OK, just understand what you mean about zero

Date 1 is right, 01 not sure

hour 1 is wrong, 01 is right

Comment: @RobG: In elderly browsers there was the so called Octal Bug. With this bug, '09' would be interpreted as octal number because of the leading zero. It was meant as a feature. '09' is not a valid octal number so it becomes 0. Better do the casting yourself and always give the base: `parseInt('09', 10)` http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=13399

Comment: @peter_the_oak—that was a feature of [ECMA-262 ed 3 *parseInt*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2), which is not used anywhere in my answer. The internal [*ToNumber*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1) method will convert `'09'` to `9` reliably. The [ES5 *parseInt*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) assumes a radix of 10, even for '09' (though browsers may not have implemented that yet).